# Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

Tags: c++

Title says what is currently stumping me with a C++ program I've made. Visual Studio reports no errors, but when I try to run it it just gives me that error. 
The program I'm doing is supposed to determine the days in a month for the user entered month, and whether or not it's a leap year. Code is below, any help is appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


enum MONTH { JAN, FEB, MARCH, APR, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC };
const string NAME_OF_MONTH[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
const int DAYS_IN_MONTH[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };


void getInput(int &month, int &year)
{
cout << "Enter a month number (1-12) and a 4 digit year " << endl;
cout << "separated by a space (or 0 0 to quit): ";
cin >> month >> year;

while (month < 0 || month > 12)
    {
        cout << "Month number must be between 1 and 12 (or 0 to quit)" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter month: ";
        cin >> month;
    }
}

void getCurrMonAndYear(int &month, int&year)
{
    time_t epochSeconds = time(NULL);

    tm * tm_ptr = localtime(&epochSeconds);

    month = tm_ptr->tm_mon;
    year = tm_ptr->tm_year + 1900;
}

bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
    if (year % 100 == 0)
        return (year % 400 == 0);
    else
        return (year % 4 == 0);
}

int numDaysInMonth(int month, int year)
{
    int numberOfDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH[month];

    if (month == FEB && isLeapYear(year))
        numberOfDays++;

    return numberOfDays;
}


int main() {

    int month;
    int year;

    getInput(month, year);

    while (month != 0)
    {
        month--;

        cout << numDaysInMonth(month, year) << "days." << endl;

        getInput(month, year);
    }
    cout << endl;

    getCurrMonAndYear(month, year);
    cout << "The current month, " << NAME_OF_MONTH[month] << " " << year << ",";
    cout << " has " << numDaysInMonth(month, year) << " days." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post a description of the error?

Comment: @JoakimE Here's the full error, minus the location since that has my name.  '"C:\Users\****\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\daysInCurrentMonth\Debug\daysInCurrentMonth.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .         **EDIT** That's all it says. It compiles, with an error about how localtime may be unsafe, and consider using localtime_s. I'm going to add #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. That may fix it, but not 100% sure.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fb19d4c-fe6c-42fb-bdd6-89dc15bf6042/not-recognised-as-an-external-or-internal-command-operable-program-batch-file

Comment: @JoakimE I did what that said, and nothing. I've pasted it in a new project, old projects, and nothing. Same error every time.

Comment: @3ncrypt3d Please go to the directory where you created the program.  Do you see the EXE there?  If you do, please run it yourself, and not using the IDE.  Does the program run?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm pretty sure you meant me, but no, I don't. There's supposed to be on there, so I'm guessing that's what my problem is? Any idea on how to get it back? Or should I just make a new program

Comment: @3ncrypt3d First, please ensure that the program did actually compile and link with no errors (see the log file).  Then ensure that you're looking for the file in the correct directory.  If the file is not there, then check if you have a virus checker program running that, for some reason, removes the EXE file that Visual Studio created.  Other than that, the executable should have been created.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The only error is the localtime may be unsafe. The log file (http://pastebin.com/Qvrwd8Ru) doesn't make much sense to me. From what I understand, the only error I'm getting is localtime may be unsafe. I don't think it's my computer either, tried it on 2 other ones, all getting the same error. **EDIT** Tried it in a new file, same error still...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Another thing, there's no .exe in the folder at all. For some reason with VS13, it's not making an exe file for this project. Other ones it does, but not this one...